# Rejection region and two sided test. Absolute value of mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-power, accept-reject

Given following problem:

[image]

I've solved this problem  assuming two sided test and rejection region $R=\{|\bar{X_n}| > c\}$ but it seems to be incorrect because correct answer assumed (I've checked it) $R=\{\bar{X_n} > c\}$.

Is a two sided test (check null)? If so then why absolute value of mean is wrong for RR?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the parameter of the alternative is larger than the parameter for the null, so there is no need to do a two sided test. In other words, you can use your statistical power all on the right tail.

Comment: Thank you very much! In other words, if I know location of alternative mean, there is no need in two sided test, meanwhile for tests like $\mu \neq 0$ I need two sided test, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's correct.